# How can I generate 128 bar code from a text box in php?

Tags: php, barcode

I have a script of 128 barcode, and it is using random number to generate a barcode, how can I make this by using textbox instead of rand in php?

This my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>asd</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $bcode = $_GET['id'];
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    include 'Code128.php';
    $code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] :$bcode; 
    header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
    echo draw($code);
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't post errors/code as images. Post the actual code/error. Images are more effort for you and us.

Comment: Look at the `method` of your form and you will know why you are getting that error.

Comment: @chris85 Sir, I've change it to


<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $bcode = $_GET['id'];


    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    include 'Code128.php';
    $code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] :$bcode; 
    header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
    echo draw($code);
}
    
?>


<form method="GET">
    
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

the error's gone but it doesn't show any barcode.

Comment: What does `draw` do? You're making us guess here. Also don't put code in comments, it is unreadable always update the question. The `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be causing the `header` call to throw an error. You can't output before `header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve the problem,

```
<form method="Get" action="barcode.php">
<input type="text" name="barcode">
<input type="submit"> 

</form>
```

barcode.php

Answer (score 0):

A textbox can't randomly generate a number...

Comment: What Im trying to say sir is, How can I make bar code through textbox value? Sorry for my english

Comment: You can retrieve the value on a page submit using    isset($_POST['submit'] {   $_POST['field'] }

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>asd</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $bcode = $_GET['id'];


    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    include 'Code128.php';
    $code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] :$bcode; 
    header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
    echo draw($code);
}
    
?>


<form method="POST">
    
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

This is my code sir,

Comment: And keeps saying this

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 12 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

asd Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMULS\Code128\sample.php on line 13 Notice: Undefined offset: -32 in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMULS\Code128\Code128.php on line 68

Comment: @GenmarDadivo The code and error belong in the question. Update it.